# how to convert Unmanaged<AnyObject>! to string

Tags: ios, swift, addressbook

I am working with Swift in my new app. here I am trying to access email-id from AddressBook. everything looks fine, but at end I am getting Unmanaged! from ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0).

so how can i convert or extract string from it?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let str = yourVar.takeRetainedValue() as String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let value : String? = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multivalue, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? String
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function to convert Unmanaged to Stirng

```
func convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: Unmanaged<AnyObject>!) -> String?{

    let value = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(
        cfValue.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as CFString
    if CFGetTypeID(value) == CFStringGetTypeID(){
        return value as String
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let value = convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multivalue, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

to Bool

```
    let obj = classType.perform(selector)
    if let obj = obj as? AnyObject {
        let pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque()
        let valueBool: Bool = pointer.load(as: Bool.self)
        return valueBool
    }
    return false
```